# Email not going through

Tags: php, symfony

I have following code:

```
$emailnew = "schools@xyz.com" 
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                    ->setSubject('New School Added')
                    ->setFrom('noreply@xyz.com')
                    ->setTo($emailnew)
                    ->setBody($view,
                                'text/html');
```

If i change email address from schools@xyz.com to schools@gmail.com it works. Is it because both email addresses are on same domain it is not working? I been trying for hours cant figure it out.

Comment: a) invalid email address b) invalid smtp configuration c) caught by spam filter. There is literally no way for us to tell you what's wrong. You'll have to start checking return values, checking server logs, blah blah blah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emails are getting filtered out due to reasons such as SPF or DKIM, probably the former, which is happening from your email provider. Update your SPF record, wait until the DNS updates, and try again.

Comment: What should i add to SPF record? I have so far: @ and static.

Comment: It depends on the setup of domains, etc.. you should look up SPF guides and possibly a generator to help you out. "@" means "this domain", a "+ip4:123.12.12.12" could be your web server if it doesn't match "this domain"'s IP address.